# Are new Paypal API credentials required after server migration?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

We've successfully been running a WordPress plugin using PayPal's Classic API integration and a custom listener URL for years.

After recently migrating the site to a new server, all IPNs related to the plugin started failing. No configuration changes have been made to the plugin or Paypal account. Our server manager insists WHM/Apache config is identical. It appears the only difference is the server IP address.

1. Would I need to create and assign new Paypal NVP/SOAP (Classic) API credentials after moving the website to a new server if the domain and plugin configuration remains the same?
2. Can I simply/safely "Remove" our existing Classic API integration and create new credentials?

Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need new API credentials.

However you should verify that any IPN notify_url specified [in the PayPal account](https://www.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/preference) or at transaction time (as part of the checkout setup) is a valid one and responding with an HTTP 200 OK status when PayPal sends an IPN.

[Review your IPN history](https://www.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/history) to see if your server is responding with another status now, such as 500 or 404 or simply no connection/response. To PayPal anything other than a 200 OK indicates a failed IPN delivery, and likely must be corrected in your system. Also there are some IPs/domains PayPal cannot connect to for various reasons, which will cause a no response status.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. IPN response code is 503 ever since the server migration, with successful 200 responses prior to the move. I'd love more info about "some IPs/domains PayPal cannot connect to" since that seems to be the only thing different.

Comment: That's not it, 503 means PayPal *is* connecting and your server is responding with the 503. It's something on your server causing it, and needs to be investigated there.

Comment: Sometimes the issue can be if you changed the email address config in the shopping cart, and IPNs are coming back with a different business email than what your system expects and hence it's throwing that error. Just a guess though, the 503 error could theoretically have any cause which can only be definitively traced/debugged within your system